# Generate Private and Public key OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, rsa, private-key, public-key

I have the following commands for OpenSSL to generate Private and Public keys:

```
openssl genrsa –aes-128-cbc –out priv.pem –passout pass:[privateKeyPass] 2048
```

and

```
openssl req –x509 –new –key priv.pem –passin pass:[privateKeyPass] -days 3650 –out cert.cer
```

... but they are not working.  For the first command I get the following error :

```
usage: genrsa [args] [numbits]
 -des            encrypt the generated key with DES in cbc mode
 -des3           encrypt the generated key with DES in ede cbc mode (168 bit key)
 -seed
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc seed
 -aes128, -aes192, -aes256
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc aes
 -camellia128, -camellia192, -camellia256
                 encrypt PEM output with cbc camellia
 -out file       output the key to 'file
 -passout arg    output file pass phrase source
 -f4             use F4 (0x10001) for the E value
 -3              use 3 for the E value
 -engine e       use engine e, possibly a hardware device.
 -rand file:file:...
                 load the file (or the files in the directory) into
                 the random number generator
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I solved the first command :

```
openssl genrsa -aes128 -out privkey.pem 2048
```

But now I'm getting an error with the second:

```
unknown option –x509
```

Comment: I wonder if the order of parameters matters?

Comment: Some of the dashes in your commands are actually en dashes (–) instead of hyphens (-).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

'genrsa' generates just an RSA key.

'req' then uses that key to make a x509 style request.

If you just need a rsa key pair - use genrsa.

If you need a keypair and a signed x509 request you use 'genrsa' and then 'req'.

Optionally 'req' can also generate that key for you (i.e. it encapsulates the 'genrsa' command (and the gendh).

So:

```
 openssl genrsa -aes128 -out privkey.pem 2048
 openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem
```

is almost equivalent to

```
 openssl req -new -x509 -keyout privkey.pem  -newkey rsa:2048
```

except that unlike 'genrsa', 'req' does not allow you to specify aes128 as the encryption.

So in a lot of enterprise settings one does it in two steps as to get sufficient control over the key encryption applied.

Comment: This command did the trick:openssl req -new -x509 -key new.pem -days 3650 -out cert.crt Many Thanks

Comment: Note that -x509 yields a self-signed certificate. Omit this option if you want to generate a certificate request.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the output, you choose wrong algorithm.
Shouldn't you pass `-aes128` instead of `-aes-128-cbc`?

From manual I assume that `-aes-128-cbc` is a proper parameter for `openssl enc`, but I don't know if it should work for `genrsa`.