How use TLS-connection in NATS
Do I understand correctly, in order to secure the system, when creating a NTS server, I can assign it a certificate, and on the client side, slip this same certificate in this way:
nc, err := nats.Connect("localhost",
nats.ClientCert("client-cert.pem", "client-key.pem"),
nats.RootCAs("rootCA.pem"))
if err != nil {
log.Fatal(err)
}
defer nc.Close()

its just questions, because I don't how create cert yet

you can create private cert pair easily ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637171/generate-private-and-public-key-openssl   ...  I suggest you create yourself a pair of certs and run your code to confirm
